# Improving my bootstrap class (MVC)

Tags: php, object-oriented, mvc, yaml

I need feedback on my Bootstrap for the MVC architecture that I follow.
I load the routes via **yaml**. Here is an example:

```
feed:
    path: /{controller}/{action}{slash}
    requirements:
        id: "[1-9][0-9]*"
        slash: "[/]{0,1}"
    methods: [GET,POST]

#Explore Controller
explore:
    path: /{controller}{slash}
    requirements:
        id: "[1-9][0-9]*"
        slash: "[/]{0,1}"
    methods: [GET,POST]
```

And here is my **Bootstrap** class:

```
class Bootstrap
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        $locator = new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../../../config');

        // DI container
        $container = new DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

        $loader = new DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, $locator);
        $loader->load('config-development.yml');

        $container->compile();

        // routing
        $loader = new Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader($locator);
        $context = new Routing\RequestContext();
        $context->fromRequest($request);
        $matcher = new Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher(
            $loader->load('routing.yml'),
            $context
        );

        try{
            $parameters = $matcher->match($request->getPathInfo());

            foreach ($parameters as $key => $value) {
                $request->attributes->set($key, $value);
            }

            $command = $request->getMethod() . $request->get('action');
            $resource = "controller.{$request->get('controller')}";

            $controller = $container->get($resource);
            $data = $controller->{$command}($request);

        }catch(\Error $e){
            $data = [
                'status'=>404,
                'message'=>'Not found',
                'info'=>$e->getMessage()
            ];
        }catch(\Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\MethodNotAllowedException $e){
            $data = [
                'status'=>404,
                'message'=>'Not found',
                'info'=>$e->getMessage()
            ];
        }catch(ResourceNotFoundException $e){
            $data = [
                'status'=>404,
                'message'=>'Not found',
                'info'=>$e->getMessage()
            ];
        }


        if(is_array($data)){
            $response = new JsonResponse($data);
        }else{
            $response = new Response($data);
        }

        //Set cors headers
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT,DELETE');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

        $response->send();
    }
```

I load the controllers and services via yaml. I'm interested if you would change anything and if you see any possible issues that this kind of structure might have.

I'm seeking for improvements in my code.

Comment: which php version are u using? Since `7.1` u can group multiple catch blocks: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/multiple-catch

Comment: @Sysix used 7+ Why you ask?

Comment: Is the goal to specifically catch instances of `Error`, `\Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\MethodNotAllowedException` and `ResourceNotFoundException` but not other Exceptions?

Comment: @SamOnela i just added it to get rid of non existing routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I haven't really used YAMLFileLoader but the advice should apply for the sake of improving PHP code*.

### Catching Exceptions

I would consolidate the exception catching, since apparently the value of `$data` is always the same (other than the fact that the `info` value is assigned the exception message). Unless the goal is to only catch `\Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\MethodNotAllowedException` and `ResourceNotFoundException` instances, why not just catch all `Exception` instances? Something like this:

```
catch(\Throwable $e){
    $data = [
        'status'=>404,
        'message'=>'Not found',
        'info'=>$e->getMessage()
    ];
}
```

And for the sake of D.R.Y. code, you could abstract setting `$data` in those exception handling blocks to a separate method that returns that array. Something like:

```
function GetFallbackDataForException(Throwable $e) {
    return [
        'status'=>404,
        'message'=>'Not found',
        'info'=>$e->getMessage()
    ];
}
```

I hadn't learned until testing out this code but an [Error](http://php.net/error) can be thrown and caught - I thought that was only possible with instances of [Exception](http://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php) but both implement [Throwable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php)...ergo...

#### Method length

The method is quite long - especially considering it is a constructor. It would be advisable to break up the pieces into separate methods - e.g. one to create the request, one to take the return value from the request and send the response, etc. That way the constructor can be shorter as it calls those methods, plus those methods would hopefully lend themselves to unit testing each component of the process.

I considered suggesting that the `foreach` to set attributes be replaced with a call to [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/array_walk) but that might require flipping the array keys and values, making a Callable out of the method, etc. all to save 1-2 lines...

Comment: Well not the kind of answer i would accept but if no body gives a better answer il accept your. Definitely some things i will include.Do you mind that i lay down my whole architecture and that you give feedback on it?

Comment: Hmm... "_lay down_" - does that mean  adding more contents to your post? I guess as long as it isn't too much ... As you likely know, it is off-topic to add links to external sites but if you can add the core elements then that should suffice. P.S. my nickname is **Nobody** ;)

Comment: Sorry i ment il write it down ahahha I'm not an native english speaker in my language it makes sense.... Don't get that part about nobody

Comment: Oh you mean include it in your code? sure! And the nickname _Nobody_ is a joke about using [indefinite pronouns](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/indefinite-pronouns/) as proper nouns - e.g. [the _Not my job_ joke](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/pronouns-notmyjob.htm).

Comment: hhaha good one.I like you man :D I'm writing it now